Why is the type can not be referred correctly?
Here is my code. The data is supposed to be referred to as one of the FeeReturnType . However, it is currently referred to as a union type of AllFee[] | ApiOrFileFee[] | DataSvrFee[] | AccountFee[].
export type FeeType = 'ALL' | 'API' | 'FILE' | 'DATA_SVR' | 'ACCOUNT';

export interface AllFee {
  name: string;
  fee: number;
}

export interface ApiOrFileFee {
  integrator_id: string;
  integrator_name: string;
  call_count: number;
  fee: number;
}

export interface DataSvrFee {
  integrator_id: string;
  integrator_name: string;
  count: number;
  fee: number;
}

export interface AccountFee {
  name: string;
  id: string;
  count: string;
  user: string;
  user_id: string;
  fee: number;
}

export type FeeReturnType<T extends FeeType> = 
  T extends 'ALL' ? AllFee[] :
  T extends 'API' | 'FILE' ? ApiOrFileFee[] :
  T extends 'DATA_SVR' ? DataSvrFee[] :
  T extends 'ACCOUNT' ? AccountFee[] :
  never;

function handleFeeData<T extends FeeType>(_type: T, data: FeeReturnType<T>): void {
  switch (_type) {
    case 'ALL':
      data.forEach(item => {
        console.log('All Fee:', item.name, item.fee);
      });
      break;
    case 'API':
    case 'FILE':
      data.forEach(item => {
        console.log('API/File Fee:', item.integrator_id, item.call_count, item.fee);
      });
      break;
    case 'DATA_SVR':
      data.forEach(item => {
        console.log('Data Svr Fee:', item.integrator_id, item.count, item.fee);
      });
      break;
    case 'ACCOUNT':
      data.forEach(item => {
        console.log('Account Fee:', item.name, item.user, item.fee);
      });
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}

const allFeeData: AllFee[] = [{ name: 'All Fee', fee: 100 }];
const apiFeeData: ApiOrFileFee[] = [{ integrator_id: '123', integrator_name: 'API Integrator', call_count: 10, fee: 50 }];
const accountFeeData: AccountFee[] = [{ name: 'Account', id: '1', count: '10', user: 'John', user_id: '100', fee: 200 }];

handleFeeData('ALL', allFeeData); 
handleFeeData('API', apiFeeData);  
handleFeeData('ACCOUNT', accountFeeData); 

code

it does look correct. the problem could be the union type and the switch statement.
try asserting/cast the data type in the switch eg: ... (data as ApiOrFileFee[]).forEach ...

Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.

You can't re-constrain generic type parameters by switch statements, at least not as of TS5.6 (it might be possible in TS5.7, or at least investigating it is on the roadmap). For now the best approach is to use destructured discriminated unions. See this playground link for why it's technically wrong to allow generics and what the fix looks like. Also see linked q/a above for a detailed explanation of the situation.
